# R Shiny: For loop only saves 1 iteration in list

Tags: r, shiny

everyone.

I am programming a simulation app in Shiny R and I am stuck at the for loops.

Basically, in an reactive I am calling a function that loops through a couple of other functions, like this:

In the server.R:

```
output.addiction <- reactive ({
                SimulateMultiple(input$no.simulations, vectors(), parameters(), input$S.plus, input$q,
                                 input$weeks, input$d, list.output)  
        })
```

The function:

```
SimulateMultiple <- function (no.simulations, vectors, parameters, S.plus, q, weeks, d, list.output) {

        for (i in 1:no.simulations) {
                        thisi <- i

                        simulation <- SimulateAddictionComponents(vectors, parameters, S.plus, q, weeks, d)  # returns list "simulation"

                        df.output <- BuildOutputDataframe(weeks, simulation, vectors)  # returns "df.outout"

                        output.addiction <-BuildOutputList(df.output, simulation, list.output)  # returns "output.addiction"

        }

        return(output.addiction)
}
```

And, again, the last function that creates the out put list:

```
BuildOutputList <- function (df.output, simulation, list.output) {
        addiction <- simulation$addiction

        output.w.success <- list(df.output, addiction)  # includes success data
        output.addition <- c(list.output, list(output.w.success))  # adds the new data to the list
        return(output.addition)
}
```

I read about the issue online a lot, I tried to isolate some stuff, to introduce a local({}) etc. But it never works. In the end, I get a list of length 1.

I would be forever grateful, if you could help me - I have been on this for two days now.

Comment: Initialise `output.addiction` outside for loop then add `[i]` undex in this line: `output.addiction[i] <-BuildOutputList(df.output...)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop in R: how to save the outputs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689387/loop-in-r-how-to-save-the-outputs)

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved itself when I edited the code in the function from

```
output.addition <- c(list.output, list(output.w.success))  # adds the new data to the list
        return(output.addition)
```

to

```
list.output <- c(list.output, list(output.w.success))  # adds the new data to the list
        return(list.output)
```

so as to not overwrite the object every time in the loop. After all - very easy and stupid problem, but hard to spot.