# Supplying several methods in a loop and saving the output

Tags: r, r-caret

**EDIT:Actually looking at the method shows it only uses one method, how can I write a loop to select a method given a vector of methods?!**

I've looked at a couple of questions([Loop in R: how to save the outputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689387/loop-in-r-how-to-save-the-outputs)) but can't seem to figure out how to save the output of these models. Here is my "function":

```
library(caret)
Control<-trainControl(method="cv",number=5)
metric<-"Accuracy"
modeler<-function(df,yname,xname,method,metric,control){
  df<-df
  methods1<-method
 f1<-as.formula(paste0(yname,"~",xname))
 for(method in methods1){
   fit<-do.call("train",list(data=quote(df),f1,metric=metric,trControl=control,
                             method=method)) 

 }
fit
}
```

An implementation of the "function":

```
methods1<-c("rf","rpart")
modeler(iris,yname="Species",xname=".",method = methods1,control=Control,
        metric = metric)
```

Now I could save the above like:

```
mod1<-modeler(iris,yname="Species",xname=".",method = methods1,control=Control,
        metric = metric)
```

And then:

```
sapply(mod1,"[",1)
```

This works but returns only the last model and in not the best of displays.
How can I optimise this process?

Comment: Try `lapply(methods1, function(met) {modeler(iris,yname="Species",xname=".",method = met,control=Control,
        metric = metric)})`, the results will now be in a list.

Comment: Perfect! Could you post that as an answer if you don't mind?

Comment: Oh,yeah! You can still post and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an abridge answer for the key parts.
With methods1 as is vector of methods one can use the lapply function:

```
methods1<-c("rf","rpart")

#use lapply to loop through the methods
#fit will be a list of the results from modeler
fit<-lapply(methods1, function(met) {
  modeler(iris,yname="Species",xname=".",method = met,control=Control, metric = metric)
})
```

If the calculations are time consuming the `lapply` function can easily made to run in parallel with the `parallel` package.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Dave2e 's comment: Here is how I've managed to "solve" it:

```
library(caret)
Control<-trainControl(method="cv",number=5)
metric<-"Accuracy"
modeler<-function(df,yname,xname,method,metric,control){
  df<-df
  methods1<-method
 f1<-as.formula(paste0(yname,"~",xname))
 for(method in methods1){
   fit<-do.call("train",list(data=quote(df),f1,metric=metric,trControl=control,
                             method=methods1)) 

 }
data.frame(fit$results,Type=fit$modelInfo$tags[1])
}
```

Implement:

```
methods1<-c("rf","rpart")
lapply(methods1, function(met) {modeler(iris,yname="Species",xname=".",
                              method = met,control=Control, metric = metric)})
```

Result with no seed: This is still lacking but it works so;

```
[[1]]
  mtry  Accuracy Kappa AccuracySD    KappaSD          Type
1    2 0.9533333  0.93 0.03800585 0.05700877 Random Forest
2    3 0.9533333  0.93 0.03800585 0.05700877 Random Forest
3    4 0.9533333  0.93 0.03800585 0.05700877 Random Forest

[[2]]
    cp  Accuracy Kappa AccuracySD    KappaSD             Type
1 0.00 0.9533333  0.93 0.02981424 0.04472136 Tree-Based Model
2 0.44 0.7733333  0.66 0.14605935 0.21908902 Tree-Based Model
3 0.50 0.3333333  0.00 0.00000000 0.00000000 Tree-Based Model
```